# Close gnome session from console

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-session

I use Ubuntu 11.10 64 bits with Gnome Shell.
I have opened a bug because sometimes "*Close session*" and "*Shutdown*" buttons doesn't work. `gnome-session-quit` only works sometimes: [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/931437)

How can I close the session cleanly from console without `gnome-session-quit`?

Answer (score 4):

The following command is an alternative for the gnome-session-quit (logout) which should close the session cleanly (not killing the gdm):

`dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1`.

(it's one line)

Comment: It works the first time but if I cancel and I try to use it again, it doesn't work. It only shows: `method return sender=:1.2 -> dest=:1.6450 reply_serial=2`. I think this is related directly with the bug mentioned before.

Comment: @Simón Probably gnome-session-quit is executing the above dbus command behind the scenes so you are hitting the same bug.

Comment: This answer doesn't work from a terminal not part of the dbus session. How do you set it up so an unrelated terminal can use another dbus environment?

Answer (score 4):

That should do it for your 'username' session

**# pkill -KILL -u username**

Comment: Thanks, but I said "cleanly". To use this, I prefer use the Ctrl+Alt+BackSpace key combination.

Comment: well, is it not as clean as "gnome-session-quit"?